# Two Inline Inputs Separated by Text

Tags: html, css

I want to place to inputs inline and separate them with some text. The reason for this is I want users to enter a start time and end time, and have the inputs relatively close each other so it looks visually pleasing.
I currently have tried to use rows and columns to achieve this, but the widths between the text are rather large due to the column. Below is some code to give an idea of my attempt. Are there any alternatives?

```
<div class = "w3-row">
   <div class="w3-col w3-container s3 m3 l3">
     <div style="text-align:right">
       <label for="hours-operation-s" class="register-labels">Hours of Operation:</label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-col w3-container s2 m2 l2" id="div-start-time">
     <input type="text" name="hours-operation-s" class="w3-input" required>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-col w3-container s2 m2 l2">
     <div class="" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">
       <p><strong>to</strong></p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-col w3-container s2 m2 l2">
     <input type="text" class="w3-input" required>
   </div>
   <div class = "w3-col w3-container s3 m6 l3">
     <!-- Blank -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple with Flexbox.

There is a reason why Bootstrap re-did their entire platform from Bootstrap3 to Bootstrap4, primarily to change from using floats to flexbox.

Flexbox requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)*

You turn flexbox ***on*** on the parent: `display:flex;`

Then, there are various *switches*. Some are set on the parent (as in the case of `justify-content`) but others might be set on the items (as with `flex-grow:1`)

#### Demo:

```css
.row{display:flex;}
.col-inline{flex:1;XXXborder:1px solid red;}
.col-left {max-width:45vw;text-align:right;}
.col-right{max-width:48vw;text-align:left;}
.col-to{max-width:5vw;text-align:center;}
.w3-input{width:80px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="div-start-time" class="col-left col-inline">
        <label for="hours-operation-s" class="register-labels">
            Hours of Operation:
            <input type="text" id="hours-operation-s" class="w3-input" placeholder="9AM" required>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-to col-inline">
        to
    </div>
    <div id="div-end-time" class="col-right col-inline">
            <input type="text" id="hours-operation-e" class="w3-input" placeholder="6PM" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### References:

[YouTube tutorial - fast-paced and best-of-breed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) for Flexbox.

***Watch the tutorial and in 30 mins from now your problem will be solved -- and you'll know flexbox.***

<sub>P.S. I have no connection to the video or its presenter - I was fortunate to discover it, and now pass it along.</sub>

Comment: I was not aware of flexboxes. Thank you. I ended up tinkering with the flexbox on w3 and achieved what I wanted. Thank you.